# Checking for collection is empty generated a ton of additional queries

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

The following code:

Example 1

```
<td>
{% if listing.catalog is not empty %}
   {% if listing.catalog.fitments is not empty %}
   Y
   {% else %}
   N
   {% endif %}
{% endif %}
</td>
```

generated in 14s and used 345 DB queries

Example 2

```
<td>
{% if listing.catalog is not empty %}

{% endif %}
</td>
```

generated in 1.7s and used 186 DB queries.

I understand that doctrine tries to pull all collection data as soon as I touch it but this is extremely expensive. Is there any more efficient way to just check if at least one collection exists?

UPDATE:

Catalog entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Fitment", mappedBy="catalog", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"createTime" = "DESC"})
 */

private $fitments;

/**
 * Get fitments.
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getFitments() {
    return $this->fitments;
}
```

Fitment entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Catalog", inversedBy="fitments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="catalog_id", referencedColumnName="catalog_id")
 */
private $catalog;
```

Comment: An alternative is to move the `empty($object)` tests into the controller and pass only non-empty objects to the template.

Comment: I think it will still run the same amount of queries but it will be done in the controller. No? I just need to check if the collection consist of any data. Kind of if I could findOneBy instead of findAll on the entity level or even query builder.

Comment: You should use a custom query and fetch the additional fields manually, even 186 queries sounds excessive.

Answer (score 1):

If you could share your Entity code and your twig template code it will be useful.

I sense there's some loop you are doing somewhere before all that. If so, you will be running into `n+1` problem. Now, if you set your relationship to `fetch=EAGER` you may have better performance, but is not recommended.

When you get a collection from the db, you get a `PersistentCollection` object. It's a proxy class that is not initialized. But if you perform any action on it, like `count()`, it will execute a query.

If you do have a loop, I would consider refactoring some of that code. Ask yourself if is really necessary to be doing that loop or think of another way you might tackle your problem. Maybe it's time to add a some `QueryBuilder` magic to the repository, or to use doctrine's built in pagination if you are working on a table for displaying data.

UPDATE:

First of all, ORM's are not made to help you create queries easily and solve your design problems. They stand for Object Relational Mappers. Their purpose is to abstract the database tables and relationship into objects, so you can work in your business logic in a more object oriented way (and get autocompletion benefits), instead of using arrays or stdClasses. Of course, they include some basic crud operations out of the box, but that is not the reason why they exist, but rather a side benefit. You as developer need to know your tools and analyze the best ways of using them.

More on that [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdO4xz64VjQ)

That being said, there are two ways of using pagination in doctrine: an easy one and a more complex one.

The easy bit is through the respective entity repository. The `findBy` method takes, besides a `$criteria` argument, an `orderBy`, a `limit` and a `offset`. So, you can do something like this:

```
<?php

$repository->findBy([], null, $request->query->getInt('limit', 10), $request->query->getInt('offset', 0));
```

That will give you the first 10 results when you perform the request. If you want to modify the size of the slice of the database, you can play with the limit and offset in the query params of your request.

The other way of using pagination, is in the `QueryBuilder`. When you are done building your query, you can just call the method `getQuery` on it. That will return the DQL Query. You can pass that to the doctrine paginator like this:

```
// Pass the first result and max result from the request object, not like I'm doing here.
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('l');
$query->innerJoin('l.catalog', 'c')
    ->innerJoin('c.fitments', 'f')
    ->addSelect('c')
    ->addSelect('f');
$dqlQuery = $query->where('some = condition')->setFirstResult(0)->setMaxResults(10)->getQuery();

$paginator = new Paginator($dqlQuery, true);
```

Then, if you iterate over that paginator you will have the items, but also some good info about how many records you have in total, and per page, so you can build an effective pagination system. More on that [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/pagination.html).

That should perform way better.

Now, of you want to just return the items that have other items in their relationships (ie, not empty collections), then you should take a look at the more advanced topic of subquerying in doctrine, by the `exists()` or `any()` methods on the query builder.

Side note: Pagination is a must for when you return a collection in any sort of application. You never want to return the whole result set at once, for obvious reasons ¿what happens when your result set grows to 10.000 records? You can easily run out of your memory limit. If you are creating a table, as I see you are doing for the few bits of code that you posted, that table must have a row limit.

Comment: That is the only difference in the twig template that is actually causing the big spike in sql queries and page load time. I already have fetch=EAGER added to the relation listing.catalog that points to fitments but it doesn't show any big difference.

Comment: Well then, there's no much more you can do. If you have many records, consider using doctrine's built-in pagination. Also, make sure you are initializing the catalog and figment properties to `ArrayCollection`.

Comment: How would you use the pagination feature on a collection? If there is not much I can do it makes the whole object relational mapping highly inefficient in such a simple scenario.